# Deducing Where Something Is By Clues That Are Implications

Tags: logic

You are given clues as to where your Christmas presents are. Supposed you start in the middle of your house and you can either go forwards, backwards, left or right. Given these 2 clues below, and that they are both true, which way should you go to find the presents? Justify.

Clue 1: If you go forwards or right, you will not find any presents.

Clue 2: If the gifts are behind you (i.e.: You have to go backwards), then you can also get the presents by going right.

Comment: Fairly easy.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Well from the first statement, you shouldn't travel north or east at all, since you won't find any gifts.

Comment: The next statement says that if the gifts are behind you, then you can go right(east), but we already scratched east off the list, so the only logical way to go is backwards or to the left, since going to the left was never even talked about in the question

Comment: So ***if*** you can go backwards then you can go right.  ***But*** you cannot go right.  So ...

Comment: So that means I can't go backwards either?

Comment: Yes.  So you can't go backwards, and you can't go forwards or right. So ...

Comment: You have to go left.. hmm very interesting.. I find this question really odd, in the way that its worded

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: as you deduced in the comments, from (2) if you can go backwards then you can go right to find the presents.  But from (1) you cannot go right to find the presents.  So you cannot go backwards to find the presents.

Combine this with (1) where if you go forwards or right you will not find any presents, implies by elimination (assuming there actually are some presents) that you need to go left to find them.